# Ajax request only handling once

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a table which has rows like in the image below. When the order online link is clicked, a form is displayed just below the row as in second image.

### FIRST IMAGE

[image]

### SECOND IMAGE

[image]

Now the thing that I am doing is initiating a ajax request when the submit button is clicked. The request is successful in the first instance. But when the request is issued again it does not work. 
It works for the same `<tr>` but when the order online of second `<tr>` is clicked and the form is loaded below that `<tr>` then, the submit ajax wont work,

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var $form  = $('.form'),  $table = $('.table');
    $table.on('click', '.link', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $table.find('tr.temp-row').remove();
        $(this).closest('tr').after(function() {
            var $tr = $('<tr class="temp-row"><td colspan="4"></td></tr>');
            return $tr.find('td').html($form).end();
        });
    });

    $("#cancel").click(function(){
      $form.hide();
    });

    $("#submit").click(function(){

      var request = $.ajax({
        url: "processform.php",
        type: "POST",
        //data: {msg : msg},
        dataType: "html"
      });

      request.done(function(msg) {
        //$("#log").html( msg );
        alert(msg);
      });

      request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
      });

      return false;
    })

  });
```

my `processform.php` page just returns some text which is alerted in the page which requests it.

Comment: Are you getting any js errors in Firebug?

Comment: @EmmyS no .. I am not getting any errors

Comment: Could you provide a DOM example? Does #submit get appended to the page with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are appending the same form with the same submit with id `#submit`. So you will have multiple submit buttons with the same ID.

You don't show your HTML for the form, but instead of using the id of the submit, you should use a class of the submit button for the click event (e.g. `$(".submitBtn").click...`).

As a side note, you should `clone` the `$form` variable in your `$table.on('click'...` event handler before assigning it to the `<td>` as that may cause problems later on.